# Spring Tool Suite - ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, spring, oracle, maven, jdbc

I keep fighting with Spring. I'm trying to connect my app with my local Oracle database, but I get that error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I figured out that the problem is the missing **.jar**, and I tried to include it, but I keep getting the same error.

I install the **Oracle JDBC JAR** in my Maven repository, I checked that it loads correctly in my project, with all the classes, etc., but still not working.

I tried to add the JAR in my Build Path, and I get the warning saying that it won't include it.

I tried *copy&paste* the JAR into the workspace, the server, the Java path... and nothing.

The only thing I couldn't do was copy it into the **WEB-INF/lib** folder (as some answers recommended), because that folder doesn't exists in my project. STS didn't created it (I assume that's because the folder structure for Spring MVC WebApplication is not the same as the usual WebApplication one).

Any ideas?

**-- UPDATE --**

My **pom.xml** as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ar.com</groupId>
<artifactId>violenciaesmentir</artifactId>
<name>blog</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
  <java-version>1.8</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- AspectJ -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency> 

  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- @Inject -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Servlet -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
        <additionalProjectnatures>
          <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
        </additionalProjectnatures>
        <additionalBuildcommands>
          <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How did you add the jar to maven? Could you list your pom.xml file?

Comment: I was trying to add it in my pom.xml, but I read that I can't do that because of the Oracle license. So, I did this:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile={ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: But how do you have your pom.xml file?

Comment: You can donwload the jar file and place on the lib of your webserver it's better in the case of driver

Comment: I said it, I tried that and still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few different options to get the what you want to do.

1. Install your own repository such as nexus, artifactory and deploy the jars in the repository, after that you can declare them as a dependency in your pom file.
2. Put the jar file somewhere on your machine (preferably `${base.dir}/lib` folder), use the system scope while declaring maven dependency and provide a systemPath for the jar. First, copy ojdbc.jar file to `${base.dir}/lib` folder.

then in your pom.xml declare the dependency as below;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Use maven dependency plugin to to include the dependencies with `system` scope;

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                    <includeScope>system</includeScope>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

3. You can also use the `maven install:install` command to install the artifact in your local repository and then declare it as normal dependency in you pom.xml file.

For example run the following;

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then declare it as dependecy in you pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**NOTE:** Option one is useful if you are group of developers and need few third party libs. This way everyone won't have to keep installing the jar in their local repo and will also provide you more control over the project dependency management. Option two and three means the project will only compile/build from your machine and will have to be configured and different machines by every time installing/copying the jar in the `${base.dir}` or local repository.

Comment: Well, I didn't get how's option one, but since I'm just making tests for myself, I tried option 3. I've already installed the JAR with Maven, I didn't declared the dependency in pom.xml, that was the fail. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me, after installing the ojdbc jar file with maven locally, was to change the scope of the dependency from the default *provided* to *compile*.

Changing the scope like this suggests that maven would have installed automatically this dependency, but in trying to solve the issue this was the sequence of steps I did for it to work.

The scope can be changed in the effective pom but for my project this dependency needed to be provided by the server and changing it from the project settings in IntelliJ did not affect the pom. (*Note that certain operations like generating and updating the sources in the maven panel can reset the settings of the project to match the pom.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems could be the incorrect url in the application configuration:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE

Check if there are missing \ or /, and also check the others params.
Check to see if you are not missing some jars in pom from Maven.

Full app configuration is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@//localhost\:1521/XE    
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver    
spring.datasource.name=XE    
spring.datasource.username=C\#\#username
spring.datasource.password=userpass    
spring.jpa.database=oracle

#hibernate configs
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect    
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```